# How do I resize the margin padding on a pdf, that has been uploaded to our document service porta?

Tags: api, pdf

[image: Document with text outside Green Dashed Margin]

I haven't been able to find an online tool to use via API, so I'm hoping one is available and you can guide me in the direction of.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to crop the file? Or did you want to achieve this programmatically? Here's an online tool that works. But I'd be hesitant to upload PDF's containing sensitive information to an online tool.

https://www.sejda.com/crop-pdf